# Moving a Python project to another machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm relatively new to Python, having only coded projects on the same machine I intended to run them on.  I'm now wanting to move several of my apps to a different machine.  I'm looking for the simplest way to do so.

I've tried using Pyinstaller to create an .exe, but it is unable to find one of my imports (docx2pdf).  I've fought with hiddenimports and still the import can't be found.  I've filed a github issue regarding this to see if the author is aware of the issue.

Apart from Pyinstaller, what is the easiest way to move a project?  I've looked at venv, but that seems fairly complex to simply move a project.  Is there a simpler way?

SOLUTION:

Thanks to legorooj.  He suggested I create a file in a subdirectory called hooks containing:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all
datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all('doxc2pdf')
```

Then build the project with the addition of a flag:

```
--additional-hooks-dir=hooks
```

Now the project builds correctly using pyinstaller.

Comment: Just like with any other Python project, you can create a `requirements.txt` file with all the dependencies and have `pip` install them for you on the target machine. It's not difficult, but it requires Python to be installed on that machine

Comment: @Todd send me an email at legorooj@protonmail.com and I'll guide you through using PyInstaller. It's unlikely that you can't get it to work with enough tweaking.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using anaconda, this is a virtual environment in which you can simply install and deinstall packages/libraries for python. Conda will keep track of the installed packages and will make sure that the installed versions are compatible.

At first glance this will look somewhat difficult but it realy isn't + it will solve all your import errors. Take a look at some of the introductions online e.g. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html